# show all certificates in a "Select a certificate" window

Tags: certificate, tomcat

My situation

I've configured Tomcat to prompt to select a certificate, however in that prompt window I can see only one certificate to select

```
 --------------------------------------
|  https://www.mypage.com--------------|------------------------------
 |  Select a certificate                                             |
 |  select a certificate to authenticate yourself to mypage.com:443  |
 |                                                                   |
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |  | Subject               |   Issuer    |        Serial         |  |                                                          
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |  | Tom Peterson          |   XXX       |        12345          |  |
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |                                                                   |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

My question

what it is needed to be done so that in that window I would see all certificates that which are installed, i.e

```
 --------------------------------------
|  https://www.mypage.com--------------|------------------------------
 |  Select a certificate                                             |
 |  select a certificate to authenticate yourself to mypage.com:443  |
 |                                                                   |
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |  | Subject               |   Issuer    |        Serial         |  |                                                          
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |  | Tom Peterson          |   XXX       |        12345          |  |
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |  | Tom the Test          |   localhost |        ABF000         |  |
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |  | random cert           |   ny_random |        00000          |  |
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |  | XXX_OP______          |   XXX       |        12345          |  |
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |  | Test                  |   Rio INC.  |        11111          |  |
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |  | Unknown               |   MS-       |        12345          |  |
 |  ---------------------------------------------------------------  |
 |                                                                   |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

for example, like on this page

https://secure.login.gov/login/piv_cac

**Clarification:**

So, I configured a Tomcat for mTLS. I created a keystore for a private key and a server certificate and created a truststore and installed CA certificates from X certificate provider. However,
when I enter a page, I can see only one certificate in a certificate window. What should I do to see all certificates in a certificate selection window that are installed on my browser?

I've installed CA Root certificate and all intermediate certificates from the same certificate issuer.

For Tomcat to ask certificates I've updated my Tomcat server.xml with
an addition piece of configuration

**clientAuth="want"**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How did you install the certificates? Are they all the same type and issuer? What prompt? How was it configured to ask for it?

Comment: On server side you usually specify a list of acceptable CAs for client authentication and this the web browser only shows you the certificates that belong to one of the CAs from that list. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57014_01/edq/DQSEC/ssl_tomcat.htm#DQSEC164